# Какие минимальные требования для Python-Разработчика(Junior)

Tags: python

Я планирую развиваться в ЯП Python в коммерческих целях. Но после изучения синтаксиса я сильно запутался. Не понимаю, куда идти дальше, где лучше развиваться и какой минимум мне нужен. Чуть-ниже укажу подробнее, что я уже изучил

**Я изучил:**

- Синтаксис
- Git(push, commit, add)
- Json
- PyAutoGUI
- Discord.py
- Начал изучать SQL(уже знаю INSERT,DELETE,SELECT)

Comment: Python довольно-таки объемный язык с множеством технологий, и нужно конкретно знать чего хочешь. Я бы посоветовал посмотреть на ютубе множество блогов/интервью с рассказами о их пути в программировании, почитать статьи, и понять, что Вам конкретно нужно. Никто так не подскажет, очень абстрактно все выглядит

Comment: Поддержу сказанное ранее. Изучи SQL т.к. базы данных нужны везде. И да, посмотри обзоры сфер где используется python, в них наверняка будут наводки на то что учить дальше. Вакансии посмотри.

Comment: Синтаксис - это хорошо, а типы данных изучили? Коллекции, например. А всякие там списковые сокращения? Декораторы?

Comment: С коллекциями более-менее разобрался, а с декорами знаком после работы с Discord(Python) и SpigotAPI(Java)

Answer (score 1):

веб, анализ данных , искусственный интеллект. Определись с направлением и загугли используемые фреймворки для этих направлений.

Answer (score 1):

Очень простой алгоритм для любого ЯП на любую позицию.

1. Гуглите "phyton junior jobs %ваш город или удалённая, если город маленький%".
2. Собираете статистику требований из вакансий (например, после 5 мин гугления и 10 вакансий могу сказать, что во всех вакансиях Phyton junior/middle упоминается обязательное знания REST-API)
3. Изучаете наиболее частые требования

+парочку своих небольших синтетических проектов и можно начинать искать работу.

Если собеседование неудачное по знаниям, то выписываете свои слабые темы, и учите, потом пробуете дальше и так по кругу.
К слову, между навыком прохождения собеседований и реальной работой общего мало.

Использовал этот метод на себе, когда устраивался на первую работу после окончания учёбы. Устроился сразу на middle позицию, правда времени обучение ушло больше. Главное, не увлекаться и не пытаться изучить всё сразу. Да и потом не выйдет узнать всё. Никогда. Так что выбирайте своё направление внимательно.

Удачи

Comment: Хороший метод, сам таким пользуюсь когда работу даже только ещё планирую менять )

Answer (score 0):

Ниже, конечно не требования приведены, но первоначальное представление о рынке с python вполне нарисует.

Вот сдесь [прекрасная статистика,](https://lp.jetbrains.com/python-developers-survey-2021/) этого года от самого python.

Такие статистики публикуются раз в год, каждый год.

Это хороший инструмент для того, чтоб быть в тренде на рынке python